# Entity-Component-System and 2D map with tiles : how to do it?

Tags: c++, entity-system

I have a question : I'm currently programming a roguelike game (with tiles) using the ECS programming paradigm, and I'm struggling with how to implement the map.

At first, I made every terrain square an entity (with a screenPosition and a sprite components), but that quickly lead to performance issues (a 100x100 map is already 10k entities).

So now, I want to treat the whole map of a level as a single entity, but I'm unsure on how to do it. Should I make a map component, that will store every terrain properties? That seems "bad" to me. Is there a better way?

Thanks

---

Edit :

My implementation is something like this :

- Each entity is a struct that store a list of pair of component_id (an int) and component_handle (an int).
- Components are struct
- an EntityManagerSystem store all the entities in a vector, and all the components, each kind in its own vector. Each vector is public, the id of each entity is its vector index, and the component handle is the component index too
- a RenderSystem that iter over the entity vector from EntityManagerSystem, and draw the ones that have the corresponding components
- an EngineSystem store pointers to all the Systems and call them sequentially to update : it's the "main" class

---

In RenderSystem, it's this loop the culprit :

em is the entityManager and CT_HASH is a compile time hash.

```
for (std::vector<GameObject>::iterator it = em->entities.begin(); it != em->entities.end(); ++it)
{
    if (it->HasComponent(CT_HASH("ScreenPosition")) && it->HasComponent(CT_HASH("Sprites")))
    {
        ScreenPosition pos = em->screenPosition[it->GetComponent(CT_HASH("ScreenPosition"))];
        if (0 <= pos.x && pos.x < xSize && 0 <= pos.y && pos.y < ySize)
        {
            Sprites sprites = em->sprites[it->GetComponent(CT_HASH("Sprites"))];
            for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
            {
                if (sprites.sprites[z] != 0)
                {
                    spriteMap[pos.x][pos.y][z] = sprites.sprites[z];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It takes around 300ms for a 100x100 map with only the terrain entities